# mapreduce - coding for multiple key and values

Tags: hadoop

In need to emit two keys and two values from my mapper. could you please provide me info , how to write code and data type for that. for example :-

```
    key = { store_id : this.store_id, 
         product_id : this.product_id }; 

  value = { quantity : this.quantity, 
            price : this.price, 
            count : this.count }; 

   emit(key, value);
```

regards

Comment: Provide a sample line from the input file and explain as an example what you need to achieve. 
Is it that one single key contains 2 parts and one single value consists of 3 parts? 

If YES, best option will be to create custom Writable for your value and WritableComparable for your key.

Comment: I have a text file eg. A B B C A R A D S D A C A R S D F A B. 
I try to find which alphabet/word is most likely to be said after the word/alphabet 'A' . in other words , I am trying to do two different sort of word count , eg . word_count(A B) and  word_count(A) then I need to find ratio  eg. 
word_count(A *) / word_count(A)

Answer (score 1):

As per the given example, A B B C A R A D S D A C A R S D F A B

From the mapper emit

```
key - A
value A, AB

key - B 
value B,BB

key - B
value B, BC

key - C
value C, CA
```

and so on...

In the reducer, you get the grouped values

```
key - A 
values A, AB, A, AR, A, AD, A, AC and so on

key - B 
value - B, BB,B,BC and so on
```

Add a delimiter of your choice between the 2 words/alphabets

for each key in reducer, you can use a hashmap/mapwritable to track the occurrence count of each value

ie for example

```
A - 5 times
AB - 7 times
```

etc etc

Then you can calculate the ratio

Sample Mapper Implementation

```
public class TestMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] valueSplits = value.toString().split(" ");
        for(int i=0;i<valueSplits.length;i++){
            if(i!=valueSplits.length-1){
                context.write(new Text(valueSplits[i]),new Text(valueSplits[i]+"~"+valueSplits[i+1]));
            }
            context.write(new Text(valueSplits[i]), new Text(valueSplits[i]));
        }
    }

}
```

Sample Reducer Implementation

```
public class TestReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Map<String,Integer> countMap= new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        for(Text t : values){
            String value = t.toString();
            int count =0;
            if(countMap.containsKey(value)){
                count = countMap.get(value);
                count+=1;
            }else{
                count =1;
            }
            countMap.put(value, count);
        }

        for(String s : countMap.keySet()){
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(key.toString())){

            }else{
                int keyCount = countMap.get(s.split("~")[0]);
                int occurrence = countMap.get(s);
                context.write(new Text(key.toString()+" , "+s), new Text(String.valueOf((float)occurrence/(float)keyCount)));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

For an input of

```
A A A B
```

the reducer would emit

```
A , A~A 0.6666667
A , A~B 0.33333334
```

AA appears 2 times, AB 1 time and A 3 times.

AA is hence 2/3 
AB is hence 1/3

Comment: thanks , can we sort this in desc order (which is already, because there  ). But lets have data set like B B A B B B B B.

Comment: what if I want to see top 3 keys only.

Comment: I did not understand the question